# How add mdSuffix component dynamically

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-material2

I'am trying to add dynamically a button to an input material component as mdSuffix, to clear the value of the input.
The problem is that I can not locate the clearable component.

`Plunker Code :` http://plnkr.co/edit/0wj67xTSameXE0qNIkad?p=preview

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question

Comment: @Benjamin HERON, are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: Yes. The proposed solution does not suit me.

I would like to add the deletion feature via a directive

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<md-form-field >
    <input type="text" mdInput >
    <md-icon mdSuffix>highlight_off</md-icon>
</md-form-field>
```

or this:

```
<md-icon mdSuffix>clear</md-icon>
```